# Run more than one lein task at the same time

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I am currently newbie in Leiningen project. I want to compile less to css using `lein-less` and `minify-assets` on the fly so I found that I should use `lein less auto` for the less file and `lein minify-assets watch` for javascripts and HTML file.

I am using `lein-cascade` to operate them but it just still on the `lein less auto` task and not go to `lein minify-assets watch`

This is my project code

```
(defproject indecorlein "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]]
  :plugins [[lein-asset-minifier "0.4.3"]
            [lein-less "1.7.5"]
            [lein-cascade "0.1.2"]]

  :min-lein-version "2.5.0"

  :cascade {
            "lessc" [["less" "auto"]]
            "min" [["minify-assets" "watch"]]
            "amp" ["lessc" "min"]
            }

  :less {:source-paths ["dev/resources/less"]
         :target-path "dev/resources/css"}

  :minify-assets [
                  [:html {:source "dev/resources/html" :target "dev/minified/html"}]
                  [:css {:source "dev/resources/css" :target "dev/minified/css/styles.min.css"}]
                  [:js {:source ["dev/res/js"] :target "dev/minified/js/amp.min.js"}]])
```

Maybe there's a solution about this or me just run the tasks on separate terminal tabs.

Comment: The double vectors for `min` and `lessc` seem a bit odd. Is that how cascade expects dependents to be specified? Also maybe try to use a word other than `min`, something that isn't already a function.

Comment: I change it to another like `minfy` name.. It still runs the `lein less auto` only..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lein-pdo` plugin. Add it into your plugins and define an alias:

```
  :plugins [...
            [lein-pdo "0.1.1"]]

  :aliases {"watch" ["pdo" ["less" "auto"]
                           ["minify-assets" "watch"]]}
```

Then you can run `lein watch` which will run both tasks at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that both `lein less auto` and `lein minify-assets watch` do not return. I've used `lein less auto` in the past in a console on its own.

Comment: So, there's no solution for this? except using different terminals

Comment: That's the simplest. On a Unix machine you could put them in the background with `&` at the end. And there's plenty of other OS options for creating daemons. I don't know of any construct with `lein` that will put them into the background for you. Maybe its a problem not worth solving.